# Using the result of a query in another query

Tags: php, sql

I have a query :

```
$sql1="SELECT column1 FROM table_A WHERE username LIKE '".$username."';"; 
// This may return multiple rows
```

Now, I need to use the result of this query in another one :

```
$sql2="select all from table_B where mycolumn equals to result we got above"
```

Comment: And whats preventing you from doing just that? fetch the result from the first query like normal and use it in the second query?

Comment: or just create a query like '$sql2="select all from table_B where mycolumn equal (SELECT column1 FROM table_A WHERE username LIKE '".$username."');'

Comment: My knowledge is poor , some help would be great

Comment: Oh would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "select all from table_B where mycolumn in (SELECT column1 FROM table_A WHERE username LIKE'".$username."')";
```

Comment: @user6650650 be aware of SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

Use JOINS:

```
 $sql = "SELECT 
                table_B.* 
         FROM table_A 
         INNER JOIN table_B ON (table_A.column1 = table_B.mycolumn)
         WHERE table_A.username LIKE '".$username."'";
```